# First time configuring cisco router by myself Why can't I reach the internet?

Tags: networking, cisco-ios

I can ping from the router Google's DNS server at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4...I can reach all inside network devices attached in the 192.168.1.X range. Other than those few addresses, I can't reach outside of my router. I have pulled an IP from my ISP. I have a route built to my next-hop address provided by my ISP.

Below is my running-config. I used a guide FROM CISCO to set this up. If anyone sees any reason why I am only able to reach these two addresses, please let me know.

```
Current configuration : 1903 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 14:49:37 UTC Wed Oct 14 2020
!
version 15.1
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname StorageRTR
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
enable secret 5 $1$3PFU$WQpG5ApsBE/6BZZpd7Oew1
enable password Probasco1!
!
no aaa new-model
!
no ipv6 cef
ip source-route
ip cef
!
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.2
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.3
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.4
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.5
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.6
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.7
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.8
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.9
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.10
!
ip dhcp pool CLIENT
   import all
   network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 192.168.1.1
   dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
!
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
ip name-server 8.8.4.4
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
crypto pki token default removal timeout 0
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FJC1931E0DD
!
!
username Rob password 0 Probasco1
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 no ip route-cache cef
 no ip route-cache
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no cdp enable
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 no ip route-cache cef
 no ip route-cache
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no cdp enable
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip nat inside source list 102 interface GigabitEthernet0/1 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.255.77.69
!
access-list 102 permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
!
no cdp run

!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 120 0
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 30 0
 login local
 length 0
 transport input all
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks ok to me, but you should not need to configure your gateway IP statically when you are using DHCP, but I guess it's working since you are able to ping Google DNS. I would remove this line:
`ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.255.77.69`

You can check if you have the right ip using this command:
`show ip int brief`

And check your route with this command:
`show ip route`

The gateway IP from your ISP is a private IP address, so the ISP will be doing NAT once more before you get to the Internet. Perhaps the ISP router is blocking stuff, like DNS to Google?

What happens if you connect a PC directly to the ISP router? Are you able to browse the Internet then? If the ISP hands out different DNS servers, try using those in the Cisco router.